# Select object by children array and object values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting data from an `object` from Facebook, and would like to select all `objects` in an `array`, that has a child value of xxx.

The `object` (simplified of course) is structured like this:

```
var friends = [
    {
        id: 123456,
        name: "Friend1 name",
        education: [
            {
                school: {
                    name: "School1 name"
                },
                type: "Highscool"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 3456789,
        name: "Friend2 name",
        education: [
            {
                school: {
                    name: "School2 name"
                },
                type: "College"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Let's assume that I want to get all objects with education.type = "Highscool". How can I do this, without looping though the entire object...?

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible without some sort of loop

Comment: I was affraid of that... :-/

Comment: And how many elements can `education` have? Should we check only the first one `education[0]`?

Comment: I assume `"Highscool"` is a typo. :-) I used `"Highschool"` in my answer, but adjust as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I do this, without looping though the entire object...?

You can't. But it doesn't have to be hard:

```
var highSchoolFriends = friends.filter(function(friend) {
    var keep = false;
    friend.education.some(function(entry) {
        if (entry.type === "Highschool") {
            keep = true;
            return true;
        }
    });
    return keep;
});
```

That uses the ES5 [`Array#filter`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.20) and [`Array#some`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.17) functions. `filter` returns a new array made up of the entries in the `friends` array for which the iterator function returns `true`. `some` loops through an array until the iteration function you give *it* returns `true` (I used it instead of `Array#forEach` because you can stop it early). If you need to support older browsers that don't have those yet, they're ones of the ones an "ES5 shim" can give you.

Or you just do the simple loops:

```
var i, j;
var highSchoolFriends = [];
var friend;

for (i = 0; i < friends.length; ++i) {
    friend = friends[i];
    for (j = 0; j < friend.education.length; ++j) {
        if (friend.education[j].type === "Highschool") {
            highSchoolFriends.push(friend);
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It's not hard, but my friend list is huge, and the app is for mobiles, so I hoped not to do alot loops. But I guess there is no other way... Thanks for your time.

Comment: @KennethB: No worries, hope that helped.